# goHUGO.io: Get Data from JSON File (object with dot)

Tags: json

I use the static site generator HUGO and i want to get the specific data from an json file that is in my /data folder:

hash.json

```
{"style.css":"style-f6891545.css","main.js":"main-84eed07d.js","main-debug.js":"main-debug-bbdd6327.js"}
```

my HTML file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/{{ .Site.Data.hash.style.css }}" />
```

this didnt work either

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/{{ .Site.Data.hash.css }}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/{{ index .Site.Data.hash "style.css" }}" />
```

Found the information here: https://gohugo.io/templates/data-templates/
under: Example: Accessing Named Values in a Data File